# RStudio on Ubuntu server: Deploying library() as admin to load/attach package for all users

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation, rstudio, admin

I'm trying to install and load/attach (the latter via `library()`) add-on packages in R as an admin in RStudio hosted on an Ubuntu server.

I've been able to install the packages just fine, so that the user at most has to run `library(package_name)` when using the package for the first time.

However, it seems that I should be able to deploy `library()` for a given package in the same way I do `install.packages()`, so that a user never needs to type `library(package_name)`. Is this possible?

As an example, for the `car` package, I've done the following in the shell of RStudio as an admin:

```
sudo R
install.packages("car", lib="/usr/lib/R/site-library")
library(car, lib.loc="/usr/lib/R/site-library")
```

After doing this, the package `car` is indeed present in the desired location (`/usr/lib/R/site-library`), but I (and other users) still have to type `library(car)` before the package can be used. My third line of code (`library(car,...)`) obviously isn't correct. Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: You could add an `~/.Rprofile` file, but loading packages automatically is usually a bad idea, as it means any scripts that neglect to call the package won't be portable to any other instance of R.

Comment: Also see https://community.rstudio.com/t/which-packages-get-loaded/298/11?u=alistaire

Comment: @alistaire I can appreciate that warning in general, but in this instance, it's for an introductory statistics course where I don't want to focus on the details of loading R packages, but rather just on using R functions. In my other classes, students do it all themselves (and not on a server). However, in this case, I would like to make the add-on package available to students (only one is needed), and simply tell them the function is housed in a package as a side note.

Comment: As long as the package is installed before startup, you can just put `library(car)` in `.Rprofile`, and it'll be run at the end of startup. In one line, `Rscript -e "install.packages('car')" && echo "library(car)" >> ~/.Rprofile`, then start R or RStudio however you like. Another option is detailed in the `?options` section on `"defaultPackages"`, which suggests a way to do it via environment variables in `~/.Renviron`.

Comment: Thanks, @alistaire - I'll give that a try.